# Count overlapping times per minute stored as a column

Tags: sql, count, amazon-redshift

I have a set of records in a redshift data base which each have a time stamp indicating the start of an activity, and a time stamp indicating the end of the activity.

```
timestamp_start     |timestamp_end
2017-01-01 01:01:31 |2017-01-01 01:48:31
2017-01-01 01:02:35 |2017-01-01 02:08:35
2017-01-01 01:09:10 |2017-01-01 02:18:10
2017-01-01 01:10:05 |2017-01-01 02:00:05
2017-01-01 01:14:58 |2017-01-01 01:56:58
2017-01-01 01:19:10 |2017-01-01 02:18:10
2017-01-01 01:25:10 |2017-01-01 01:54:10
2017-01-01 01:30:23 |2017-01-01 01:56:23
2017-01-01 01:36:26 |2017-01-01 03:06:26
2017-01-01 01:37:03 |2017-01-01 02:14:03
2017-01-01 01:37:15 |2017-01-01 02:08:15
2017-01-01 01:37:55 |2017-01-01 02:58:55
2017-01-01 01:42:49 |2017-01-01 02:59:49
2017-01-01 01:44:10 |2017-01-01 03:23:10
2017-01-01 01:46:49 |2017-01-01 02:58:49
2017-01-01 01:49:34 |2017-01-01 02:15:34
2017-01-01 01:52:11 |2017-01-01 02:38:11
2017-01-01 01:52:45 |2017-01-01 03:31:45
2017-01-01 01:54:15 |2017-01-01 02:17:15
2017-01-01 01:55:14 |2017-01-01 02:40:14
```

It is a simple method to count the occurrence of a new activity per minute with the following:

```
select date_trunc('minute', timestamp_start) as minute, count(*) as count
  from myTable
  group by 1
```

Similarly counting the end of an activity:

```
select date_trunc('minute', timestamp_end) as minute, count(*) as count
  from myTable
  group by 1
```

However, how can I count the activity in each minute that is 'ongoing' [edit: for every minute in some range]? i.e. in minute group 01:01 we had a new activity start. In minute 01:02 we had another new activity start, but the activity from 01:01 *has yet to finish*, and therefore the count of *current activities* is two. Conversely the count of records at 02:00 must *not* include any of the 4 records that have finished before that minute.

Further, the solution must also not 'explode' the data, i.e. join the records to a different table of 'prepared' minutes to provide multiple duplicates of the records, and then count the length of the resultant table.

I have attempted the following:

```
SELECT
  minute,
  count(CASE WHEN timestamp_end > minute AND timestamp_start < minute) AS tmp
        FROM (
          SELECT minute
          FROM (
                 (
                   SELECT date_trunc('minute', timestamp_start) AS minute
                   FROM myTable
                   GROUP BY 1
                 )
                 UNION ALL (
                   SELECT date_trunc('minute', timestamp_end) AS minute
                   FROM myTable
                   GROUP BY 1
                 )
               ) s1
          GROUP BY 1)
```

However I suspect that I have badly formed the case argument, and may well be missusing it. I also have looked at window functions however, I cant see an obvious way to count forward to include the 'currently active' records only.

Comment: Unfortunately your current query has both logical problems and syntactic problems; so you may have to go somewhat back to the drawing board. First question: how do you want to determine which minutes are included in the output?  Every minute in some range?  Every minute with a non-zero count?  Other...?

Comment: Could you please add to your question the expected result based on the sample output you provided? Your description is quite thorough, but still I'm afraid there's some room for misunderstandings

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Every minute in some range, will update

Comment: @StefanoZanini, will update

Comment: Since you want every minute, you need a way to create a result set of _all_ minutes from the earliest start timestamp, to latest end timestamp. I'm not sure how you can do that at Amazon Redshift but I'm sure there is a way. When you have this result set you can do an inner join with your table on condition that the minute is between start and end timestamps. Finally you can count the number of rows for each minute and eliminate 0s if you'd like.

Comment: @infiniteRefactor Thanks, but I actually don't need all the minutes. Also for various reasons irl, the task is to do exactly not that. "Further, the solution must also not 'explode' the data, i.e. join the records to a different table of 'prepared' minutes to provide multiple duplicates of the records, and then count the length of the resultant table."

Comment: @DaveRGP ok, but note that you definitely need to do some 'exploding' at some point. Even you will restrict the result to a specific range, you want your result set to include data points that do not exists at the original table. In order to achieve that you either need to 'explode' the data, or do some procedural style computation (like loops at TSQL). You can not do that with pure SQL.

Comment: @DaveRGP - to be fair, no decent database is going to implement the query that InfiniteRefactor describes by literally making `N` copies of the event records.  As I said in my answer, if the concern about this is speculative (rather than based on observed problems with this approach) then I really think it ought to be tested before being rejected.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** - Another suggestion at the end, based on Stefano Zanini's idea...

---

**Original thoughts**

To generate output a single minute, you could of course do something like

```
select count(*)
  from myTable
 where $minute between timestamp_start and timestamp_end
```

From an SQL perspective, saying that you want each record counted for the output rows of each minute in that event's range, but also that you don't want to "explode" the data against a list of minutes, is a bit of a contradiction.  I assume your concern is about performance and/or resource usage to run the query; which I suppose could be a problem for large enough data sets, but still it's probably worth testing this approach if you haven't already.

**Another Option that Might Work**

Now as I commented on Stefano Zanini's answer, what he's suggesting won't quite work.  But it does suggest an approach that might work: first capture the minutes during which the count changes, then post-process to get values for every minute.

To get a list of minutes when the count could change

```
select distinct minute from (
    select date_trunc('minute', timestamp_start) as minute from my_table
    union all
    select dateadd('m', 1, date_trunc('minute', timestamp_start)) as minute from my_table
)
```

This may give you a much smaller set of minutes to join against the table.

You might be able to get something more like his query to work by using an outer join (and doing something to avoid dup records; haven't worked this out), but the self-join would cause the same level of "data explosion" as this version of the original approach.

There's some dispute about what might be wrong with his query, so consider this:

Both approaches try to limit the sample times against which to "explode" the data, and then try to count the data that corresponds to each selected sample minute.

The functional problem with Stefano's way of selecting samples is that he only picks the start times of events.  But actually the count can change at the end of an event as well.  So consider

```
Start         Stop
10:00         10:15
10:05         10:20
```

Now Stefano's query will produce records for 10:00 and 10:05, and you have to interpolate the values for any other minute.  You will correctly infer a value of 1 form 10:00 to 10:04, and a value of 2 from 10:05 to 10:15.  But you will *also* infer a value of 2 for 10:16, because the query doesn't tell you anything changed at that time.  Which is wrong.

Now you *could* add even more complexity to the query to account for that; but the counting logic is already more indirect / complicated in his version (and just because he's listed the trade-offs of different counting approaches doesn't mean any one of them is precise or suitable for a given purpose).  Or you could do it in a simple and direct way.

---

And if none of that works (or you don't want to use it for some other reason) then I don't know that SQL is the tool you need for this job.  Maybe a procedure that iterates over minutes and accumulates the counts into a temp table?  Or if there's a service layer (java or something) between the database and the user, then maybe do the counting there?

Comment: thanks, this was the conclusion I am coming to as well, the data is large, and the current method is an 'explosion". I've been tasked to 'avoid the explosion', though tbf I haven't been limited by tools. I am new to sql, and wanted to make sure that I hadn't overlooked something.

Comment: Would you mind providing an example such that my solution would fail?

Comment: @StefanoZanini : Would've been happy to discuss after your first comment, but after your second? You're on your own.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Removed my comment since that annoyed you, please go ahead

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, I think you need to use as to assign the aliases to make it work. I definitely do in Redshift.

Comment: @DaveRGP - Sorry, I don't use redshift much.  It does vary by dbms.  Will update.

Comment: @StefanoZanini - Deleting your comment doesn't change what I think of your attitude, but since I'm updating anyway I'll include a note about what's wrong with your version.  Stand by.

Answer (score 0):

I think the task can be accomplished with a self join, with the start date of the left table being between the start and end date of the rows on the right side table.

```
select  t1.timestamp_start, count(*)
from    test t1
join    test t2
on      t1.timestamp_start >= t2.timestamp_start and
        t1.timestamp_start < t2.timestamp_end
group by t1.timestamp_start
```

This works fine, but the output is not the count per minute, but the count per `timestamp_start`. Extracting the minute from that field poses a new question: minutes 37 and 52 have more that one task starting in them, what count should you show for them?

This is the max / min option

```
select  date_trunc('minute', tt.timestamp_start),
        max(tt.cnt) as max_cnt, /* this is probably the value you want */
        min(tt.cnt) as min_cnt
from    (
            select  t1.timestamp_start, count(*) as cnt
            from    test t1
            join    test t2
            on      t1.timestamp_start >= t2.timestamp_start and
                    t1.timestamp_start < t2.timestamp_end
            group by t1.timestamp_start
        ) tt
group by date_trunc('minute', tt.timestamp_start)
```

The sum option is simpler (note that the query below gives the same result as the query above aggregated with `sum`, because the grouping condition is less strict):

```
select  date_trunc('minute', t1.timestamp_start), count(*)
from    test t1
join    test t2
on      t1.timestamp_start >= t2.timestamp_start and
        t1.timestamp_start < t2.timestamp_end
group by date_trunc('minute', t1.timestamp_start)
```

You can find a working example [here](http://rextester.com/GLCU64322); rextester doesn't have a redshift emulator, but SQL Server has functions that do the same task, so no big deal.

Comment: Generally won't produce expected results. Won't produce a record for the start of the first event, or any other event that starts when no other is in progress. Will produce multiple, potentially contradictory, records for minutes in which multiple events start.

Comment: The first event issue is handled with `>=` instead of `>` in the first `join` condition, and the second problem you point out is debated in the second part of my answer. You can see all the queries in action at the link I added

Comment: thanks, I will test, but in the mean time what do you mean by 'the sum option is simpler'? I don't see a sum in your code.

Comment: You're right, it's probably a bit obscure. I edited my answer with a bit of explaination